# Submit button not work while using ClientValidation of asp.net mvc 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have one form with text box, submit button, drop down list ..... I'm using `<%Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>` to validate all the elements in my form.  But the probem is when I write `<% using (Html.BeginForm()){ }%>`, the validation works, But when I click on the submit button, it did nothing even though I complete all the condition of each elements. And the submit button is submitting while I use `<form method="post">` instead of `<% using (Html.BeginForm()){ }%>`.

I use jquery tab in my view, so I have more than one submit button that do different task(I test the value of the submit button in my controller). 
[image: this is my view]

Could any one tell me, what did I wrong here?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make sure that you wrap your entire form in the braces when using the `<% using (Html.BeginForm()){ }%>`. If your submit button is not contained within those braces, then it will not cause the form to post.

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm()) { %>

... form elements here ...

<% } %>
```

When you use this method, remove the other form tags on the page as this syntax is equivalent to writing:

```
    <form>

    ... form elements here ...

    </form>
```